# Python for loop ignoring if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

For some reason python is ignoring my if statement, even if the `str(search)` is in my list `lista` it still prints the elif statement regardless.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
search = input("what would you like to search for?:")
    for n in range(len(lista)):
         if str(search) in lista[n]:
             print(lista[n])
         elif str(search) not in lista[n]:
             print("search not found in list")
             break
```

Comment: Why are you using `elif` instead of just `else`?

Comment: It was something in lista, it works if i remove the elif statement but i want to have it to notify a user if its not found, it does the exact same even if i use else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `elif` will end the loop (because of the `break`) if the `search` wasn't found **at the first position** (because the `if` and `elif` are executed for each item in your list). In your case you could simply use a "trigger" to indicate at least one finding and do the `if` after the loop:

```
found = False
for n in range(len(lista)):
     if str(search) in lista[n]:
         print(lista[n])
         found = True
if not found:
     print("search not found in list")
```

However better would be to iterate over the list directly instead of a range of the length:

```
found = False
for item in lista:
     if str(search) in item:
         print(item)
         found = True
if not found:
     print("search not found in list")
```

If you don't like the trigger you can also use a conditional comprehension to get all the matches and use the number of matches as indirect trigger:

```
findings = [item for item in lista if str(search) in item]
if findings:  # you got matches:
    for match in findings:
        print(match)
else:         # no matches
     print("search not found in list")
```

Comment: Thank you, the first set of code works perfectly. I opted to go to for the first because lista is a list of lists.

Comment: @czedarts All of them should do the same, even if it's a list of list. But I'm glad it worked. Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Regarding "if you don't like the trigger", the flag variable can easily be replaced with a `for`-`else` construct, provided one uses `break` to bail out of the for loop if something was found.

Comment: @blubberdiblub As far as I understand the purpose of the code: It should print all matches. In that case a `break` isn't a good choice and then you can't use `else`.

Comment: @MSeifert yes, indeed, that precludes breaking out.